# How to write a LinkedList to a .txt file

Tags: java, methods, linked-list

Super simple program. Loop asking for student data (name, address, gpa) which is stored in a linked list. Output the data to a regular text file that can be opened in notepad.

I'm so close, but cannot figure out how to get my data written into the txt file. To start, here's my classes:

```
public class Student {

    private String name;
    private String address;
    private double gpa;
        
    public Student(String name, String address, double gpa) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.gpa = gpa;
    }
        
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
        
    public String getAddress()  {
        return this.address;
    }
        
    public double getGpa()  {
        return this.gpa;
    }
    
    public String toString()  {
        return this.name + ", " + this.address + ", " + this.gpa;
    }
```

```
public class WriteFile {
    private String path;
    private boolean append_to_file = false;
    
    public WriteFile(String file_path)  {
        path = file_path;
    }
    
    public WriteFile(String file_path, boolean append_value)    {
        path = file_path;
        append_to_file = append_value;
    }
    
    public void writeToFile(String textLine)throws IOException  {
        FileWriter write = new FileWriter(path, append_to_file);
        PrintWriter print_line = new PrintWriter(write);
        print_line.printf("%s" + "%n", textLine);
        print_line.close();
    }
}
```

```
public class ReadFile {
    private String path;
    
    public ReadFile(String file_path)   {
        path = file_path;
    }
    
    public String[] OpenFile() throws IOException   {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(fr);
        
        int numberOfLines = 3;
        String[] textData = new String[numberOfLines];
        
        int i;
        
        for (i=0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
            textData[i] = textReader.readLine();
        }
        
        textReader.close();
        return textData;
    }
    
    int readLines() throws IOException  {
        FileReader file_to_read = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(file_to_read);
        
        String aLine;
        int numberOfLines = 0;
        
        while ((aLine = bf.readLine()) != null) {
            numberOfLines++;
        }
        bf.close();
        return numberOfLines;
    }
}
```

In main I can get it to write the "Text to be written to file" into my .txt file, but I still can't figure out how to write studentData into that file.

```
    public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    LinkedList < Student > studentData = new LinkedList < > ();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    scanner.useDelimiter(System.lineSeparator());

    while (true) {
      System.out.println("Student name: ");
      String name = scanner.next();
      if (name.isEmpty()) {
        break;
      }

      System.out.println("Student address: ");
      String address = scanner.next();
      System.out.println("Student GPA: ");
      double gpa = scanner.nextDouble();

      studentData.add(new Student(name, address, gpa));

    }

    studentData.sort(Comparator.comparing(Student::getName));

    for (Student info: studentData) {
      System.out.println(info.getName() + "," + info.getAddress() + "," + info.getGpa());
    }

    String file_name = "C:\\Users\\hidden\\OneDrive - hidden\\Desktop\\Portfolio_Project.txt";
    try {
      ReadFile file = new ReadFile(file_name);
      String[] aryLines = file.OpenFile();
      int i;
      for (i = 0; i < aryLines.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(aryLines[1]);
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Error. Please try again.");
    }

    // Write to a file

    WriteFile data = new WriteFile(file_name);
    data.writeToFile("Text to be written to file");
    System.out.println("Text File Written To Portfolio_Project.txt on Desktop");
  }

}
```

Comment: Personally I would construct the method `WriteFile.writeStudents(List<Student> students)`
btw your class names should be noun-based, so not `WriteFile` but `StudentFileWriter` (assuming you're only writing `Student`s to it). Also method names, camel case, beginning lower case

Comment: Thank you for the insight on class names. Which methods are you seeing as not camel case? I have my constructors in standard upper case beginning, but did I miss a method or two without camel case?

Comment: What part of this are you having trouble with? What happens when you run your code? Are you getting any errors? If so, what are they? If not, what is the output and how does it differ from what you want instead?

Comment: I can't figure out how to get the studentData into the .txt file. I can print it out on the screen, I can also pass a string into my .txt file, but I can't seem to determine how to get the studentData into the .txt file.

Comment: Camel casing is OK. `OpenFile` should be `openFile`. No underscores apart from in all-capitalised constants

Comment: Thank you @g00se. Can you provide a little more detail around your suggested method? I'm not 100% sure how that method would work. My LinkedList is studentData but I don't have a students variable.

Comment: What's the difficulty? You have a linked list of `Student`. You already have a method `writeFile`. You just need to make another one like that which will write the whole `List` in a loop

Comment: @g00se I tried to create that new method, but I'm only getting it to write the last studentData entry to the .txt file.

```
 public void writeStudents(LinkedList<Student> students) throws IOException {
  for (Student info:students) {
   FileWriter write = new FileWriter(path, append_to_file);
   PrintWriter print_line = new PrintWriter(write);
   print_line.printf("%s" + "%n", info);
   print_line.close();
        }
 }
```

Comment: I actually played around with it more and got it to work.

``
public void writeStudents(LinkedList<Student> students) throws IOException {
 FileWriter write = new FileWriter(path, append_to_file);
 PrintWriter print_line = new PrintWriter(write);
 for (Student info:students) {
  print_line.printf("%s" + "%n", info);
    }
 print_line.close();
}
``